# Reparametrization of Curves and Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, surfaces

First let me introduce the definitions then I will come to my actual doubt.

**Parametrized Curve**- A parametrized curve is smooth map $\gamma : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$, where $I$ is open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.


**Parametrized Surface**- A Parametrized surface is smooth map $\sigma : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $\sigma : U \rightarrow \sigma(U) \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is homeomorphism onto its image, such that $\{\frac{\partial \sigma (u,v)}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial \sigma (u,v)}{\partial v}\}$ is linearly independent for all $(u,v) \in U$.Then $S=\sigma(U)$ is called parametrized surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$, where $U$ is open subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

**I want to know what is the motivation for doing this reparametrization of curve and surfaces ?** In the case of curve, I have something, that is, due to the reparametrization the rate of it transverse. For example, Arc length parametrization gives the unit speed on the curve. But still need proper motivation of doing it for curves.

Also, What about in the case of reparametrization of surface? What is benifit/motivation doing the reparametrization of surfaces?

Note that I am not giving explanation of what do we mean by reparametrization of curves and surfaces.

Comment: Usually for curves, one reparametrizes  to calculate curvature. When a curve is arc-parametrized, the modulus of the second derivative gives you its curvature.

Comment: @janmarqz , It means that to fulfil the requirement of unit speed curve we do reparametrization of curve. For this we do arc length parametrization. Right?

Comment: yes,  if $C(t)$ has $||C'(t)||=1$ then $\kappa=||C''(t)||$. Condition $||C'||=1$ implies that $C''$ is perpendicular to $C'$.

Comment: There is, sadly, no analogue of arclength parametrization for surfaces unless they happen to be flat (zero curvature). But at least you might agree that parametrizations with $\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u} \cdot \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}=0$ would be easier to work with. If you don't know this yet, you soon will.